# Clojure Macros: When can a function not duplicate a macro's behaviour?

Tags: clojure, macros

I'm playing around with clojure macros and I'm finding that a lot of macro behavior I can just replicate with function composition.

A good example of this is the threading macro:

```
(defn add1 [n] (+ n 1))
(defn mult10 [n] (* n 10))

(defn threadline [arg]
  (-> arg
      add1
      mult10))
```

I can replicate this easily with a higher order function like pipe:

```
(defn pipe [& fns]
  (reduce (fn [f g] (fn [arg] (g(f arg)))) fns))

(def pipeline
  (pipe
   #(+ % 1)
   #(* % 10)))
```

There must be instances where a macro can not be replaced by a function. I was wondering if someone had some good examples of these sorts of situations, and the reoccurring themes involved.

Comment: In theory, any can do the others' job, both being turing complete and all. Whether you'd want to, though, is another matter.

Comment: @dsm Not true. Macros don't have to evaluate all of their arguments, but functions do. Also, macros cannot be passed to higher-order functions such as `map`, but functions can.

Comment: No they don't. You have lazy eval and lanbda for that

Comment: *lambda - silly fat stubby fingers...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One important advantage of macros is their ability to transform code at compile-time without *evaluating* any of it. Macros receive code *as data* during compilation, but functions receive *values* at run-time. Macros allow you to extend the compiler in a sense.

For example, Clojure's `and` and `or` are implemented as recursive macros that expand into nested `if` forms. This allows lazy evaluation of the `and`/`or`'s inner forms i.e. if the first `or` form is truthy, its value will be returned and none of the others will be evaluated. If you wrote `and`/`or` as a function, all its arguments would be evaluated before they could be examined.

Short-circuiting control flow isn't an issue in your `pipe` function example, but `pipe` adds considerable run-time complexity compared to `->` which simply unrolls to nested forms. A more interesting macro to try to implement as a function might be `some->`.

> I'm finding that a lot of macro behavior I can just replicate with function composition

If your functions are amenable to it, you can certainly replace a simple threading macro with function composition with `comp`, similar to "point free" style in other functional languages: `#(-> % inc str)` is functionally equivalent to `(comp str inc)` and `#(str (inc %))`.

It's generally advised to prefer functions when possible, and even when writing a macro you can usually farm out most of the "work" to function(s).

Answer (score 4):

The first macro I ever learned is a good example of a macro that can't be written as a plain function:

```
(defmacro infix [[arg1 f arg2]]
  (list f arg1 arg2))

(infix (1 + 2))
=> 3
```

Of course this exact macro would never be used in the wild, but it sets the stage for more useful macros that act as readability helpers. It should also be noted that while you *can* replicate a lot of basic macro's behavior with plain functions, *should* you? It would be hard to argue that your pipe example leads to easier to read/write code than, say, `as->`.

The "reoccurring themes" you're looking for are cases where you're manipulating data at compile-time ("data" being the code itself), not run-time. Any case that requires the function to take its argument unevaluated must be a macro. You can partially "cheat" in some cases and just wrap the code in a function to delay evaluation, but that doesn't work for all cases (like the `infix` example).

Answer (score 2):

Macros are not interchangeable with functions, but you examples are:

```
(macroexpand '#(+ % 1))
; ==> (fn* [p1__1#] (+ p1__1# 1))
```

The reason why it works is because the argument expect a function and you use a macro that becomes a function.  However I know that `cond` is a macro. It cannot be replaced with a function implementation since the arguments of a function gets evaluated and the whole point of `cond` is to only evaluate some parts of the arguments in a specific order based on evaluation of their predicates. eg. making a recursive function with that would never terminate since the default case will also always be called before the body of the function cond is evaluated.

The whole point of macros is to expand the lamguage and since the evaluation is controlled by the result you can make all sorts of new features that would be impossible with function except if one passed all arguments as functions to delay evaluation.

Comment: That was clarifying. I'm also trying to get to the bottom of this, but find most responses really confusing. The line seems too blurred for an uninitiated in Clojure to tell them apart. Would you be able to provide one or two of these examples you mentioned at the end of your answer? Thanks for sharing this response!

Answer (score 2):

In any language, macros -- compile-time functions from code to code -- let you do three things:

1. Define new binding forms (e.g. Clojure's destructuring `let`).
2. Change the order of evaluation (e.g. `or`, `and`).
3. Present a domain-specific language (e.g. Instaparse).

You can debate 3 -- whether implementing DSLs truly *requires* macros. Sure you can do code generators that are functions from text files to text files. Or, sure you can do Ruby style runtime DSLs. But if you want a DSL that's integrated into the compiler at compile-time, then macros are effectively your "compiler API".

Having said that, it makes sense to use macros only for these special purposes. Use functions and/or data-driven code as much as possible. Including to do work behind the "facade" provide by a macro.

Answer (score 1):

The two big things macros do is control evaluation of their arguments and transform code at compile time. You can do both with functions by requiring calling code to quote their arguments.

For instance, you could write a version of `defn` that is called this way:

```
(defn 'name '[arg1 arg2]
  '(expression1)
  '(expression2)
  'etc)
```

Then you could `eval` arguments at will, evaluating them or not, changing the order of execution, or altering forms before you evaluate them, exactly the things macros are good for.

What macros can do that functions can't is gain this ability without any cooperation from the calling code. Users can call macros as if they were plain functions and don't have to treat their arguments any differently.

That's how macros allow you to extend the language: you don't have to treat macro code any differently than regular code, unlike, say, JavaScript, Ruby, or Python, where the language can only be extended with new control flow constructs by doing what you've done in your example, wrapping code in a block, lambda, or function.

Comment: You can't actually write `defn` in this way, at least not if you want all of its current functionality. The important difference is that `eval` lacks access to lexical scope, so something like `(let [x 1] (defn* 'foo '[] 'x))` can't work, where `(let [x 1] (defn foo [] x))` works fine.